# How can I connect my eclipse program to SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, jdbc

I am just a new programmer., can someone please give me a step by step procedure on how to connect my eclipse program to sqlite?

Comment: I don't think this question is really suitable for SO. It's also not clear what you mean. Do you want to brows your DB inside the IDE? Make a program that browses the DB? You have linked tags from Android and .Net. We don't even know what you are working with.

Answer (score 0):

from http://wiki.eclipse.org/Connecting_to_SQLite 
1) Download the SQLite drivers from: [1]. The actual zip file with the driver is at [2]. Expand the zip somewhere locally and note the location.

2) Put the sqlite_jni.dll from the zip into your JRE's bin directory. The driver requires this file to be in the java library path.

3) In Eclipse with DTP 1.0 installed (preferably the final build or a nightly build dated 110806 or later), go to the Preferences (Window->Preferences) and select the Connectivity->Driver Definitions page.

4) Select the "Generic JDBC" category in the Available Driver Definitions tree and click "Add...".

5) Select "Generic JDBC Driver->Generic JDBC Driver" in the Available Driver Templates tree. Give the new generic JDBC driver a name like "javasqlite JDBC driver". Click OK.

6) Click "Add Jar/Zip" and select the sqlite.jar from the driver zip you expanded in step 1. Click Open.

7) In the Properties table, select the Driver Class property and click the "..." button. If the jar is accessible, you will see a dialog appear with at lease one class in the list. Select "SQLite.JDBCDriver". Click OK.

8) Also in the Properties table, select the Driver URL property and type the following: jdbc:sqlite:/DRIVE:/dirA/dirB/dbfile

9) Click OK on the Edit Driver Definition dialog. You should see your new driver appear in the driver list on the Driver Definitions preference page.

10) Click OK to close the Preferences dialog.

11) If the Data Source Explorer is not open, open the Connectivity->Data Source Explorer view from the Window->Show View menu or open the Database Development perspective from the Window->Open Perspective.

12) In the Data Source Explorer, right-click on the Databases category and select New...

13) In the New Connection Profile wizard's Wizard Selection Page, choose the SQL Model-JDBC Connection entry in the list and click Next.

14) Give your new profile a name like "SQLiteTestDB". Click Next.

15) In the "Select a driver from the drop-down" combo box, select your new SQLite driver definition. Modify the file path in the sample URL to match the path to your local SQLite database.

16) Click "Test Connection" to verify you can connect to your database.

17) Click Finish to create the profile.

18) In the Data Source Explorer, right-click on the new profile and select Connect. You should see content appear in the tree beneath the profile. Browse through your database to view available tables and their columns.